# Bootstrap - Modal only shows the first item

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I'm using Bootstrap to design this webpage. This page contains a table where I use `modal` to show more details about the selected item.

My problem is that all buttons on the table only redirects to the first detail of the first item. I was thinking of the id name and making it into array, but it does not work (or I did it wrong).

Here's a sample code to give you an idea:

```
<?php
(loop){

$itemtopic=$loop['item'];
$data=$loop['data'];

?>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float:right; margin-left:5px;" title="New User"><?php echo $itemtopic; ?></button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New User</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo $data; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<?php
} /* END OF LOOP */
?>
```

How can I show the corresponding data with the selected item and not only just the first detail of the first item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to loop the modal elements, What you need is change the data before displaying the modal.  please try the following code:

```
<script> 
 //Please visit http://www.nokiflores.com
   $(document).ready(
    function() {
         $("button.btn").click(    
             function(e) {
             var parent_div =  $(this).closes("div");
             var val =   $(parent_div).find("input[name=data]").val();
             $("#modal_body").html(val );
              $("#myModal").modal();
          });
    } ); 

});

    </script>

<?php $_data = array(); $_data[] = array('id'=>1,'data'=>"data1", 'item'=>"item1");  $_data[] = array('id'=>2,'data'=>"data2", 'item'=>"item1");  ?>

<?php foreach($_data  as  $data ) { ?>

<div class="data">

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data['data'] ; ?>" name="data" />

<!--please notice that i remove the modal functions in this  button-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="<?php echo $data['id'] ; ?>" style="float:right; margin-left:5px;" title="New User"><?php echo $data['item'] ; ?></button> 

</div>

<?php } ?>



            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New User</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="modal_body" class="modal-body">

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Logon Wayne, its a little bit vague on whether you are doing this, so can you please confirm whether you are printing X buttons with X modals and that they have Matching Unique ID's for each pair?

For example:

```
<?php
$rows = array('1'=>"afasdf",'2'=>"fagagadfg"); 

foreach($rows as $key=>$data):
?>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $key;?>" style="float:right; margin-left:5px;" title="New User">Create New User</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo $data; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
endforeach;
?>
```

The key is unique ids, else ofcourse it will find and display the first modal title #myModal.

You could only use 1 modal if you used ajax to replace the content on each load, which issnt what you are doing and really doesnt seem needed unless you have truly massive amounts of html printing due to this loop, in which case pagination would be a logical next step anyway.

: )

Comment: Sorry, but your answer, which is dynamically changing the `data-target` for the button, did not help my problem, yet. And I'm also waiting for other answer that can easily help me. Because I think this is an easy question, it is just that I don't know how to solve it by myself.

Comment: @LogonWayne, can you please share the code you use that doesnt work, because your not 'dynamically' changing anything, your needing to print a seperate modal for each seperate button with matching unique ID->data-target