# Bootstrap Modal with mysql data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html table with list of Product Name and ID, upon clicking the Product Name Link I wanted to open a Modal and show the Item with respect to ID.

I wanted to pass $code to the Model and retrieve data. How should I do?

My code below..

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-code="@<? echo $code; ?>">Product 1</a>
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-code="@<? echo $code; ?>">Product 2</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?
                $code_id = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : false;
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id=:code LIMIT 1");
                $result->bindValue(':code', $code_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->execute();
                $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $unit = $row['unit']; $name = $row['name']; $price = $row['price'];
                ?>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">#</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Unit</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Product Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><? echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $unit; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $name; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $price; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is, is your current code not working?

Comment: You should use ajax for this.

Comment: Can you please guide me? coz I donno how to $_GET data inside Modal. If Ajax how to implement?

Comment: do you want each different modals for different rows or one modal for all your data?

Comment: You can also refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059086/bootstrap-modal-only-shows-the-first-item

Comment: I have a HTML list with Product 1, Product 2 and so on.. Each Product Name is an anchor. So when I click each of it, it should open a Modal with the Product Details of that Particular Product. So each time the anchor is clicked Modal should give single Product's details.

Comment: @LoganWayne That link I don't understand... Kinda confusing..

Answer (score 1):

I realized Logan's answer wouldn't work because he was targeting classes instead of Ids. `data-target` for each link to modal should be a unique id. I created a variable $uid (unique identifier), and initialised it to one (alternatively you could use your primary key).  Each modal will have an id of `myModal+$uid`, and each link will point to a specific modal's id.

```
<?php 
     $code_id = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : false;
     $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id=:code LIMIT 1");
     $result->bindValue(':code', $code_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $result->execute();

     //checks if there are results before sending it to the while loop
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         $uid = 1;//alternatively you can use your primary key from the table
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $uid; ?>" data-code="@<? echo $code; ?>">Product <?echo $uid?></a>


  <!-- start modal, realise the id of each modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $uid; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal fade">
    <!--the rest of your code-->
  </div>

<?php 
      $uid = $uid +1;//increase uid        
      }// end while 

 }//end if statement ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data-target` of your link would determine what modal to open. So you have to link the attribute of `data-target` by having the `class` attribute of your modal the same with the `data-target` attribute of your link.

Try this:

```
while(/* YOUR CONDITION FOR FETCHING DATA FROM YOUR DB */){
  ?>
    <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>" data-code="@<? echo $code; ?>">Product 1</a>
  <?php

  <!-- START OF MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade myModal<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>" .....>
    <!-- REST OF MODAL CODE -->
  </div>

} /* END OF LOOP */
```

Just replace the `$uniqueid` with your primary key.

Comment: That means if I have have 100 Products, I'm creating 100 Modals within that While Loop. right?

Comment: @tmariaz - sorry. I get back to you too late. I updated my answer and the `class` of your modal should be `modal fade myModal<?php $uniqueid; ?>` instead of `modal fade bs-example-modal-lg<?php $uniqueid; ?>`. Just look at my updated answer.

Comment: I'm still stuck... is anyone can help?